# Metric space analog for manifold with boundary

Tags: geometry, reference-request, metric-spaces, metric-geometry

I tried to define an analog of manifold with\without boundary for metric space and I wondered if this definition or a similar one exists in the literature. 
Let $\left(X,d\right)$ be a connected metric space we say that

> it is without "boundary" if there exists an $r\in \mathbb{R}$ s.t. for every $x,y\in X$ there exists a $z\in X$ s.t. $d\left(z,x\right)=r$ and $d\left(z,y\right)=d\left(z,x\right)+d\left(x,y\right)$.

Under this definition a sphere with the intrinsic metric is a space without boundary while a disc is space with boundary. 
Note: We may want want to include the condition that the metric space is a length metric space in the definition.

Comment: This property does not seem to hold for the open half-plane (or other open susbets of Euclidean space).

Comment: But the open (!) half-plane is a perfectly fine manifold without boundary. Should it rather be an analog of closed/complete manifolds without boundary?

Comment: yeah open set would be considered spaces with boundary even though they don't have boundary in the manifold sense

Comment: I'm hoping to find a defention for this in the  literature but if one doesn't exists maybe give it a different name

Comment: A closely related notion is "a space with extendible geodesics" (or "with geodesic extension property"). https://www.intlpress.com/site/pub/files/_fulltext/journals/sdg/2006/0011/0001/SDG-2006-0011-0001-a010.pdf There is also a notion of "boundary" in Alexandrov geometry (for metric spaces of curvature bounded below).

Answer (score 0):

Define a metric $d$ on $\mathbb{S}^2$ : $d(x,y)=\sqrt{d_0(x,y)}$
where $d_0$ is canonical metric on $\mathbb{S}^2$. It is not
intrinsic metric.

Consider $X$, which is Euclidean cone over $  \mathbb{S}^2$ as a set, s.t.
$$d_X((s,x),(t,y))=|s-t|+d(x,y) $$